# TF Frame Convention for Stereo Cameras

Tags: calibration, camera-info, image, stere-image-proc, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a stereo camera for both stereo reconstruction and monocular image processing. Since I am not calibrating the pair of cameras twice, I am doing all of the monocular processing using the stereo calibration parameters. For the camera intrinsics, this works fine. I am not sure how to handle the extrinsics.

I would like to have the left and right cameras in different TF frames that correspond to their positions on my robot (e.g. `/stereo_left_link` and `/stereo_right_link`). Since the stereo baseline is encoded in the stereo calibration parameters, I am not sure `stereo_image_proc` will deal with the two images being in different TF frames.

What is the correct way to set the `CameraInfo` and `Image` message `frame_id`s to safely proceed to avoid being affected by the potential inconsistencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9824/tf-frame-convention-for-stereo-cameras/) by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 524 on 2011-04-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could check out uvc_camera's [stereo_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera#stereo_node_.2BAC8_StereoNodelet) as somewhere to start.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

typically each camera in a stereo pair is assigned a different tf frame and the camera info for each camera contains the frame information

```
# Time of image acquisition, camera coordinate frame ID
Header header    # Header timestamp should be acquisition time of image
                 # Header frame_id should be optical frame of camera
                 # origin of frame should be optical center of camera
                 # +x should point to the right in the image
                 # +y should point down in the image
                 # +z should point into the plane of the image
```

stereo_image_proc listens on the right/camera_info and left/camera_info topics

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks for the link, but it is solving a different problem. I would like left/{image,camera_info} to have TF frame /stereo_left_link and right/{image,camera_info} to have TF frame /stereo_right_link. However, this triggers an assertion that left.frame != right.frame.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-18**:
if you look at this question http://answers.ros.org/question/106/how-to-add-kinect-sensor-input-to-a-urdf-model#175 this is how we model the kinect for the turtlebot

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2011-06-17**:
I believe I have already tried this, but stereo_image_proc complains that the left and right TF frames do not match.